# Download PDF error in third party web panel

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am browsing my website using IE or chrome, pdf is download without any issue. But if I try from the web panel the error issue will come out,
`Error in function Anonymous function(http://localhost/payment/js/jspdf.min.js:1:8985): Object expected.`
My IE version is 11. Below is a screenshot of the error message.

[image: output1]

In the jspdf.min.js:1:8985 code is:

[image: output2]

What I've tried. I use the `jspdf.debug.new` to debug the error. The error message is `Error in function Anonymous function(http://localhost/payment/js/jspdf.debug.new.js:1178:11): Object expected.`

Start in the line 1178 in the jspdf.debug.new.js is

```html
          saveAs(getBlob(), options);
          if (typeof saveAs.unload === 'function') {
            if (global.setTimeout) {
              setTimeout(saveAs.unload, 911);
            }
          }
```

[image]

This is the IE version:

[image: output3]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.